# ksh function returns 0 instead of "?"

Tags: linux, function, shell, ksh

I encountered a problem, that a ksh command in a legacy ksh script behaves strangely in one enviromment but not another.

These 2 environments have :

- the same version of ksh ***Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01***
- almost the same contents in `.profile`
- same output of `cat /proc/version`

  > Linux version 3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-039.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon Feb 20 02:37:52 EST 2017
- the same output of `locale` :

  > LANG=C
  >   LC_CTYPE="C"
  >   LC_NUMERIC="C"
  >   LC_TIME="C"
  >   LC_COLLATE="C"
  >   LC_MONETARY="C"
  >   LC_MESSAGES="C"
  >   LC_PAPER="C"
  >   LC_NAME="C"
  >   LC_ADDRESS="C"
  >   LC_TELEPHONE="C"
  >   LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
  >   LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
  >   LC_ALL=

Inside of this legacy ksh script, there's a function who

- executes a sql query
- stores the result in a temporary file
- removes the title (column name) and `\r` characte from the temporary file,
- assigns the value to a variable,
- returns the value of this variable as the function's result by `echo`

Here's an example of implementation of this function

```
function get_value {

  # A temp file to store sql query result
  TEMP_FILE="/tmp/get_value_tmp.txt"

  # here's a bloc of code that executes a sql query
  # then store the result in ${TEMP_FILE}
  # execute_sql_query is just a pseudocode who launches database request program

  if execute_sql_query << EOF
    # ...
    # code do send request against database
    # write the result to the tmp file ${TEMP_FILE}
    # ...
EOF

  then

    # removing the title (column name) and \r characte from the temporary file
    # assign the value to a variable RET
    RET=`tail -n +2 $TEMP_FILE | tr -d '\r'`

    # the varible is returned as the result of this function
    echo $RET

  else

    # in case of sql query execution fails
    # CR is a variable who gets error code of execute_sql_query
    CR=$?

    # retrun error code as function result
    echo $CR
  fi
}
```

The sql query's result was exported to `${TEMP_FILE}`, inside of this `${TEMP_FILE}`, we have :

```
val_str
?
```

when the variable `RET` get the value `?`

The strange thing is,

- in one environment the function returns **incorrectly** a `0`, as it interprets the `$RET` as `$?`
- in another environment it returns **correctly** a `?`

the function `get_value` is in a ksh script `script_A.ksh`
the `script_A.ksh` is called in another ksh script `script_B.ksh`
the script `script_B.ksh` is launched as a background job by `nohup ksh script_B.ksh &`

Has anyone encountered the same problem, does anyone have some ideas to analyse this issue, please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your terminal's LC_CTYPE environment.

Comment: Can you try `printf "%s\n" "$RET"` ? Also, what if you add false: `RET=`tail -n +2 $TEMP_FILE | tr -d '\r' ; false; `? Then `$?` should be `1`, will it write 1?

Comment: @IporSircer thx for your response, here's the output of `locale`
LANG=C
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=

Comment: Have you try a "set -x" within that function ? Just wondering if the if/then/else statement is printing $RET on one of the server but $CR on the other which would explain the result "0"

Comment: @dppi i mean compare the two environments.

Comment: @IporSircer, I have the same output of `locale` on these 2 environments

Comment: Thx @AndreGelinas, I have `set -x` within the script, and I'm sure that the sql query export a value `?`, I checked the database log too, the query was run successfully. I changed the code `echo $RET` to `echo "${RET}"`, the function returns correctly a `?`, so I am sure that the block of code after `then` was executed

Comment: Since there must be a difference somewhere...have you made a diff between the 2 temp file ?.. I know...grabbing at straws here